# Multiple threads access shared resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, opengl, sdl

I'm currently working on a particle system, which uses one thread in which the particles are first updated, then drawn. The particles are stored in a `std::vector`. I would like to move the update function to a separate thread to improve the systems performance. However this means that I encounter problems when the update thread and the draw thread are accessing the `std::vector` at the same time. My update function *will* change the values for the position, and colour of *all particles*, and also almost always resize the `std::vector`.

**Single thread approach:**

```
std::vector<Particle> particles;
void tick() //tick would be called from main update loop
{
    //slow as must wait for update to draw
    updateParticles();
    drawParticles();
}
```

**Multithreaded:**

```
std::vector<Particle> particles;
//quicker as no longer need to wait to draw and update
//crashes when both threads access the same data, or update resizes vector
void updateThread()
{
    updateParticles();
}
void drawThread()
{
    drawParticles();
}
```

To fix this problem I have investigated using `std::mutex` however in practice, with a large amount of particles, the constant locking of threads meant that performance didn't increase. I have also investigated `std::atomic` however, neither the particles nor `std::vector` are trivially copyable and so can't use this either.

**Multithreaded using mutex:**

**NOTE**: I am using SDL mutex, as far as I am aware, the principles are the same.

```
SDL_mutex mutex = SDL_CreateMutex();
SDL_cond canDraw = SDL_CreateCond();
SDL_cond canUpdate = SDL_CreateCond();
std::vector<Particle> particles;
//locking the threads leads to the same problems as before, 
//now each thread must wait for the other one
void updateThread()
{
    SDL_LockMutex(lock);
    while(!canUpdate)
    {
        SDL_CondWait(canUpdate, lock);
    }
    updateParticles();
    SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);
    SDL_CondSignal(canDraw);
}
void drawThread()
{
    SDL_LockMutex(lock);
    while(!canDraw)
    {
        SDL_CondWait(canDraw, lock);
    }
    drawParticles();
    SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);
    SDL_CondSignal(canUpdate);
}
```

I am wondering if there are any other ways to implement the multi threaded approach? Essentially preventing the same data from being accessed by both threads at the same time, without having to make each thread wait for the other. I have thought about making a local copy of the vector to draw from, but this seems like it would be inefficient, and may run into the same problems if the update thread changes the vector while it's being copied?

Comment: You should also consider whether exploiting data parallelism could be a more suitable approach. The update and draw actions won't be that different for all those particles, will they?

Comment: They are almost identical functions, could you explain what you mean? I'm not familiar with the concept of data parallelism.

Comment: Updating the particles likely happens with some loop over that vector, let one thread work on the first half and another on the second half. Generalise for more threads.

Comment: Interesting, I like this idea but would it work if one thread resized the vector? How would that affect the other threads?

Comment: No that would not work. Though you can handle that like this: 1. compute the update function of all particles, resulting in one *collection* of new/updated particles for every particle. 2. Flatten those collections into an updated single collection/vector. Step 1 is trivial to parallelize, step 2 a bit more tricky. But assuming that computing the update function is far more complex than just copying/moving particles objects around one should still get acceptable speedup.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a more granular locking strategy.  Instead of storing a `particle` object in your `vector`, I would store a pointer to a different object.

`struct lockedParticle {
   particle* containedParticle;
   SDL_mutex lockingObject;
};`

In `updateParticles()` I would attempt to obtain the individual locking objects using `SDL_TryLockMutex()` - if I fail to obtain control of the mutex I would add the pointer to this particular `lockedParticle` instance to another vector, and retry later to update them.

I would follow a similar strategy inside the `drawParticles()`.  This relies on the fact that draw order does not matter for particles, which is often the case.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. You are correct in assuming that my draw order doesn't matter, however if I was drawing using alpha blending then this may become a problem. To be clear, are you suggesting that I declare a local vector within my `updateParticles();` and push the pointers to locked particles on it, then update this local vector afterwards? Would this not again encounter problems if a new update cycle had started when I try to draw the local vector?

Comment: No.  I am suggesting that your globally-accessible vector contains pointers to a new structure.  The new structure contains an individual mutex that locks individual particles.  So whether drawing or updating, you use the same individual lock per particle.  When iterating through this vector (in either method), you maintain a separate vector of objects you have to re-visit at the end of the method's loop, for objects that could not be locked.

Comment: Alternatively you could look at using a lock-free strategy, where the update method updates the entire particle object atomically.  For this you could not use vector<> though.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing this up, but i believe my point still stands. Say a particle couldn't be locked, and so it's added to the new vector, then at the end of the function when i try to revisit them, if a new update cycle has started then these particles may still not be lockable?

Comment: Yes, in this case I would not update them and leave those particles for the next cycle - with 10,000 particles on screen this might not be a problem.  With 3 or 4 it would be.  I would personally go with my alternate suggestion, of a lock-free list.  This would allow consistent read-only access to all particles at all times, and multiple threads can update consistently at once.  If you only need write-access from a single-thread, the implementation becomes even simpler (because you don't need to do the Compare And Exchange call), you would just swap in the new particle into your linked list.

Answer (score 1):

If data consistency is not a concern you can avoid blocking the whole vector by encapsulating vector in a custom class and setting mutex on single read/write operations only, something like:

```
struct SharedVector
{
    // ...
    std::vector<Particle> vec;

    void push( const& Particle particle )
    {
       SDL_LockMutex(lock);
       vec.push_back(particle);
       SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);
    }
}
//...
SharedVector particles;
```

Then of course, you need to amend `updateParticles()` and `drawParticles()` to use new type instead of `std::vector`.

**EDIT:**
You can avoid creating new structure by using mutexes in `updateParticles()` and `drawParticles()` methods, e.g.

```
void updateParticles()
{
    //... get Particle particle object
    SDL_LockMutex(lock);
    particles.push_back(particle);
    SDL_UnlockMutex(lock);
}
```

The same should be done for `drawParticles()` as well.

Comment: Your `push` function would be a solution to adding new particles to the vector, but my issue is also that the position of a particle can be changed as it is accessed for drawing, would I need to add new functions for accessing the position using a mutex in the same way?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, in multithread environment you need to guard all accessing operations to your vector.

Answer (score 1):

If the vector is changing all the time, you can use two vectors.  `drawParticles` would have its own copy, and `updateParticles` would write to another one.  Once both functions are done, swap, copy, or move the vector used by `updateParticles` to the to be used by `drawParticles`.  (`updateParticles` can read from the same vector used by `drawParticles` to get at the current particle positions, so you shouldn't need to create a complete new copy.)  No locking necessary.

Comment: This would double my memory usage? So then it becomes a matter of speed vs. memory if I understand your answer. Also, I know that it's hard to tell without actually testing it, but do you think this would improve my performance? I'm not sure how much of a performance hit comes from copying the vector.

Comment: @nitronoid It probably will increase your memory usage, but it might not be all that bad depending on the changes you're already making to the vector in `updateParticles`.  The speed improvement is something you'd have to test (profile), because that depends a lot on many factors.  Locks, particularly when used frequently, can become bottlenecks.  This has the advantage of being fairly easy to implement and test, without the possibility of forgetting a lock someplace.